# OBJ Mapping Texture Strange Coordinates

Tags: opengl, textures, lwjgl

I'm trying to load textures from an OBJ file with LWJGL, but there seems to be places where the textures aren't loading correctly. It's supposed to look like this without the lighting:

[image: img1]

But it looks like this:

[image: img2]

Anybody have an idea of what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LWJGL, the texture files have to have a resolution of some power of two by that same power of two (ex: 256x256, 128x128, 512x512). Try making your textures fit this size, maybe that will help.